# preg_replace not working on simplexml_load_files

Tags: php, xml, regex

It was working, bur something happened and all the sudden not working any more.

```
$vehi = simplexml_load_file('http://apps.cbp.gov/bwt/customize_rss.asp?portList=250401&lane=all&action=rss&f=csv');
$sysd =  $vehi->channel->item->description;
$ret = preg_replace("/(^.*?Commercial\s)/","",$sysd);
```

The above code is suppose to cut  everything before the word commercial, but nothing is happening, I'v tried different thing all day but cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DOTALL (s)` flag that will make you match newlines also while using `.*`:

```
$ret = preg_replace("/(^.*?Commercial\s)/s","",$sysd);
```

Comment: O.o Oh my God... It worked (Y) Thank You, Thank You... :) That was it

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Don't know people down voting this question.

Comment: I don't mind if I get down voted, I'm sure you answer will help others whit the same problem so, Than you a lot.